# Get inside data between tags (regexp)

Tags: javascript, regex, match

How I can get all data between tags?

My RegExp: `\<table id\=\"listtable\".+\>(.*)\<\/table\>`

result:

[image]

I think it because there are line breaks. How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it match across multiple lines you can use this regex:

```
/<table id="listtable"[\s\S]*>([\s\S]*)<\/table>/ig
```

Use of `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` makes it match it across new lines.